# how to exclude files in /storage/emulated/0/Ringtones

Tags: java, android, android-cursoradapter

When I use `adb` I can't find the `/storage/emulated/0` folder. I am basically trying to load all audio files in `internal storage` but trying to exclude system specific audio like ringtones and notification tones like touch tones etc. I have the following code:

```
String[] mediaAttrs = {
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                };
mCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
              MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,mediaAttrs,null,null,null);

String[] excludeLocations = {"/system","/storage/emulated/0/Ringtones"};

boolean locationInclude = true;
 while(mCursor.moveToNext()){
                String mediaLocation = mCursor.getString(mediaLocationIndex);//required column index
                for(String eachLocation:excludeLocations){
                    if(mediaLocation.startsWith(eachLocation)) {
                        Log.e("LocationTest:Excluded"," "+mediaLocation);
                        locationInclude = false;
                    }
                }

                if(locationInclude){
                    Log.e("LocationTest:Included"," "+mediaLocation);
                    this.insert( ... );//insert found data
                }
                locationInclude = true;

            }
```

Then I use the following to populate the list view:

```
Cursor mPlayListCursor = mDB.getWritableDB().query(
                Audio,//table name
                new String[]{"_id","mediaLocation"},
                null,null,null,null, "mediaLocation"+" ASC"
        );

SimpleCursorAdapter mAudioAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mCursor,
                new String[]{"mediaLocation"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0
                );  
ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.mListView);
lv.setAdapter(mAudioAdapter);
```

The most weird thing is, all the audio files under `/system` get excluded but two files:

1. `/storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/hangouts_incoming_call.ogg`
2. `/storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/hangouts_message.ogg`

always appear in the `ListView`, the folder doesn't exist when I view it using `adb`, what is this folder? Is it created at runtime? Then how do the audio get there? And How am I supposed to avoid them from being populated in the `ListView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + " not like ? and " + 
MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA +  " not like ? ";
String [] args = {"%" + "ringtones" + "%", "%" + "system/" + "%"};

Cursor mCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,mediaAttrs,selection,args,null);

while(mCursor.moveToNext()){
       // mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)
   String mediaLocation = mCursor.getString(1);//required column index
   Log.d("LocationTest:Excluded"," "+mediaLocation);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit about what the % mean?

Comment: this query actually gives an error. I don't know if the column name is wrong. (I found out about the % similar to sqlite not like statement)

Comment: To find the tracks whose names contain the "ringtones" or "system" literal strings, you use % wildcard at the beginning and end of the pattern.